# $X$ topological space and $S\subseteq X$ and $\overline{S}=X$. Show that if $S$ is connected, then $X$ is also

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

$X$ topological space and $S\subseteq X$ and $\overline{S}=X$. Show that if $S$ is connected, then $X$ is also.

First of all, what is the intuition behind this? For example, what is a subset $S$ such that $\overline{S} = X$?. I can't even think of such thing... Is it a space that is almost $X$? And then when we take the closure and it's $X$. Well, what argument should be used to argue that $X$ will also be connected?

Comment: Such sets $S$ are called "dense", and the classic nontrivial example of a dense set is $\Bbb Q\subset\Bbb R$. Of course, this isn't connected, so it's not relevant for your statement. For a connected dense set, you can think of $(0,1)\subset [0,1]$, or less trivially, try removing a finite collection of line segments from $\Bbb R^2$. (this doesn't always work, but sometimes it will)

Comment: $\bar{S}=X$ means $S$ is dense in $X$, look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dense_set

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $X$ isn't connected. Then there are closed sets $V, W\subsetneq X$ with $V\cup W=X, V\cap W=\emptyset$. Then we have relatively closed sets $V\cap S\subseteq S, W\cap S\subseteq S$ with $(W\cap S)\cap (V\cap S)=\emptyset$ and we also have $W\cap S\subsetneq S$ and $V\cap S\subsetneq S$, then if e.g $W\cap S= S$ was correct, we had $\bar{S}\subseteq W\subsetneq X$.

So all in all we see $S$ isn't connected, a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

Assume that there is a continuous surjection $\varphi:X\rightarrow\{0,1\}$ and we let without loss of generality that some $s\in S$ be such that $\varphi(s)=0$. As $S$ is connected, we have $\varphi[S]=\{0\}$. Then for any $x\in X-S$, we could find some net $\{x_{\delta}\}\subseteq S$ such that $\varphi(x)=\lim_{\delta}\varphi(x_{\delta})=\lim_{\delta}0=0$, it violates the condition that some $x\in X$ is such that $\varphi(x)=1$.

Comment: what is $\varphi|_{S}=\{0\}$?

Comment: The restriction of the function $\varphi$ on $S$ is the constant function which is of value $0$.

Comment: @user284331: Your notation, however, is incorrect: $\varphi\upharpoonright S$ is not the set $\{0\}$. What you mean is that the *image* of $S$ under $\varphi$ is $\{0\}$, i.e., that $\varphi[S]=\{0\}$. You could also write $\operatorname{ran}(\varphi\upharpoonright S)=\{0\}$.

Answer (score 0):

Assume X is not connected. Then X=Y U Z where Y= U{B(y)|y is in Y and S} and Z=U {B(z)| z is in Z and S} are non-empty. Then S=Y' U Z' where Y'=U{B(y) intersect S| y is in Y and S} and Z'= U {B(z) intersect S | z is in Z and S}. These are open sets in S.

Comment: What's $B$? Boundary?

Comment: What's $U$? I cannot understand your notation

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs U is a union; B is some arbitrary ball or neighborhood of the indicated point.